# ジェネリックが絡むオーバーロードの解決

Tags: c#

オーバーロードが存在するメソッド `Second()` を、ジェネリックメソッド `First()` から呼び出しています。
`First()` に `int` を渡したときは `Second(int)` が呼ばれてほしいのですが、`Second(object)` が呼び出されてしまいます。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.First("string")); // "object"
    Console.WriteLine(this.First(1)); // "object" ("int" が返ってきてほしい)
}

private string First<T>(T args)
{
    return this.Second(args);
}

private string Second(object args)
{
    return "object";
}

private string Second(int args)
{
    return "int";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++のtemplateに慣れていると当然そうなってほしいのですが、C#のジェネリックでは実行時に判断するしかなさそうです。

```
private string First<T>(T args)
{
    if (args is int)
        return this.Second((int)(object)args);
    else
        return this.Second(args);
}
```

上記だと`Second()`のオーバーロードが増えるたびに`First()`を改修する必要があります。
それが嫌なら`dynamic`にキャストすることで実行時にオーバーロード解決をすることができます。

```
private string First<T>(T args)
{
    return this.Second((dynamic)args);
}
```